# Does the Oracle JDBC Driver SetBigStringTryClob property still work?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, driver

I write a piece of code to try to figure out how `SetBigStringTryClob` works. I did not set the `SetBigStringTryClob` property and try to insert a `String` which's length is `68717` to a Clob using `PreparedStatement.setString()`, but to my surprise, it works without any exception or warning.

I decompile the Oracle JDBC Driver and try to find if there are any `SetBigStringTryClob` in the source code, but I find nothing.

I check the `OraclePreparedStatement`'s `setString()` method and find that if the String is big enough, `setString()` will use Clob automatically.

So, does the Oracle JDBC Driver's `SetBigStringTryClob` property still works or it has been disabled after a release？My Oracle JDBC Driver's version is 11.1.0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the latest documentation, that property is not available in your 11g R1 driver:

> "The SetBigStringTryClob connection property of Oracle Database 10g Release 1 (10.1) is no longer used or needed."

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oralob.htm#CHDGEIHF